# Excel 2007 data collection

Tags: excel-2007

aI have an Excel 2007 workbook with about 150+ worksheets and I want to select the data from the same same cell in all worksheets and copy the data (it is all text) from only those cells that contain data; to a separate worksheet with the data listed in a column.

Comment: Do you want to do this somehow from Excel (not possible I believe), or write a program in SSIS or C# to parse the Excel file and pull out the cell? Basically, what is your question, how do you hope to get this solved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following VBA:

```
Dim WriteCell as Range
Set WriteCell = Sheets("New Sheet").Range("A2")

Dim MySheet as Worksheet
For Each MySheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If MySheet.Range("B2").Value <> "" Then
        WriteCell.Value = MySheet.Range("B2").Value
        WriteCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = MySheet.Name
        Set WriteCell = WriteCell.Offset(1,0)
    End If
Next
```

That's if it's the same worksheet within that workbook. If you want it to be some other workbook, replace the `For Each` line with this:

```
Workbooks.Open File:= "C:\MyBook.xlsx"
For Each MySheet in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

This will just iterate through all of the worksheets, testing that value, and generating a worksheet with Worksheet Name and Cell Value as columns.